# Jquery find by multi spec

Tags: jquery, find, element

Is it possible to add class 'active' to element found with jQuery based on "not active" and "not hidden"?

You have with 'not active'

```
addClass('selected').closest('.well').find('ul li:not(.active)').addClass('active');
```

but this does not function:

```
.addClass('selected').closest('.well').find('ul li:not(.active)').find('li:not(.hidden)').addClass('active');
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply chain multiple `:not(...)`:

```
.addClass('selected').closest('.well').find('ul li:not(.active):not(.hidden)').addClass('active');
```

Comment: This is perfect, thx! .addClass('selected').closest('.well').find('ul li:not(.active):visible').addClass('active');